Knitting Error message due to library() loading packages
Hi all trying to knit my R assessment together. Note the packages on lines 23-28 do run with no error message in the code chunk only an error pops up when try to knit and  I am getting this error message:

Error: ! package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse':  .onAttach
failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:   call: NULL
error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyr' in loadNamespace(j
<- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace 'cli' 3.4.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required
Backtrace:

rmarkdown::render(...)
knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
knitr:::process_file(text, output)
knitr:::process_group(group)
knitr:::call_block(x)
...
base::withRestarts(...)
base (local) withRestartList(expr, restarts)
base (local) withOneRestart(withRestartList(expr, restarts[-nr]), restarts[[nr]])
base (local) docall(restart$handler, restartArgs)
evaluate (local) fun(base::quote(<smplErrr>))

Quitting from lines 23-28 [unnamed-chunk-2]
(Week-7-Formative_Assessment.Rmd) Execution halted

This is what is on lines 23-28:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

Can someone tell me what's going on? thanks
Have tried reinstalling tidyverse, updating all available packages, installed packages on console. Have tried separate the code chunks to run separately but no avail. Packages run fine in code chunk but when i go to knit code its says error in those lines. I am new to R so bare with me if its a simple mistake!
